# Is it possible to call a module of another project from the current one in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am kind of new to VB, and I have to do a group project, so I needed to know, is it possible to create a button on a Windows Form, that when clicked it is able to call a module from a different project.

What we are trying to do is create a quiz-tutorial on space topic. I am working on the tutorial part and he is working on the quiz part so I wanted to know that is there a way to link 2 or more project together, like if I was to create a button called "Test" in one of my modules and when its clicked it starts running my friends project.

Comment: You can add a reference to another project in the references section of your project. Right click References in VS and add a new one.

Comment: How does that work? I've added references but how can i call another module by clicking a button

Comment: Make sure you've got a reference to the namespace of the other module in your current module using the using statement such as: `using MyFriend.HerModules' and then you can start using classes within that namespace.